# How to update adjacent tab from a BottomTabNavigator tab in React native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, bottomnavigationview

Im using react-navigation for react native. I have three screens inside a bottomtabnavigator. One of them contains a location picker(for eg.). I want to update the location details in the two other pages too whenever user picks a new location. How can i listen for location change from adjacent tabs?

Comment: May be try using setParams from react-navigation in combination with componentDidUpdate on other two tabs.

Comment: But how can i setParam from a different screen. Im not making any navigations programatically.

Comment: refer this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

Comment: @hong develop params is wont work for bottomnavigator. those are meant for stacks i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I started using contex api to achive this.  The update code is written common in the provider and Updates are made by calling from the children wrapped by Consumer.